# remove empty outline in ggplot bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(time = rep(1:10, 2),
                 value = c(0,0,0,0, abs(rnorm(6)),
                           0,0,0,0,0, abs(rnorm(5))),
                 group = c(rep("B", 10),
                         rep("A", 10)),
                 group_fill = c(rep("no", 7),
                              rep("B", 3),
                              rep("no", 7),
                              rep("A", 3)) )
```

I plot this as a stacked bar chart:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = time, y = value, color= group, fill = group_fill)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#333333")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#FFFFFF")) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:10) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

From the data set it is obvious that the first 5 observations for "B" and the first 4 obervations for "A" are exactly zero.

However, ggplot adds a little orange outline for these value.

How can I remove the orange outline for "A" in the first 1:5 observations?

It is important that I want time 5-7 to have no fill, i.e. only outlines.

A second question would be how can I make the "group" legend filled with blue and orange and not grey?

Comment: Why not just filter out times which all values are zero?

Comment: For replacing the legend fill you can use `scale_color_manual(values=c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#333333"), guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9")))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited to turn the zero's into NA's, which seems to work.

```
df <- data.frame(time = rep(1:10, 2),
                 value = c(0,0,0,0, abs(rnorm(6)),
                           0,0,0,0,0, abs(rnorm(5))),
                 group = c(rep("B", 10),
                           rep("A", 10)),
                 group_fill = c(rep("no", 7),
                                rep("B", 3),
                                rep("no", 7),
                                rep("A", 3)) )

 df[df == 0] <- NA

  ggplot(df, aes(x = time, y = value, color = group, fill = group_fill)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#333333"), guide = F) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#FFFFFF")) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:10) +
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: I forgot to add that I want the outlines like I have it, only the zeros should have not outlines

Answer (score 2):

Subset the data frame to exclude zeroes `subset(df, value != 0)`, and remove the legend for colour with `guide = FALSE`:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(time = rep(1:10, 2),
                 value = c(0,0,0,0, abs(rnorm(6)),
                           0,0,0,0,0, abs(rnorm(5))),
                 group = c(rep("B", 10),
                         rep("A", 10)),
                 group_fill = c(rep("no", 7),
                              rep("B", 3),
                              rep("no", 7),
                              rep("A", 3)) )    
    ggplot(subset(df, value != 0), aes(x = time, y = value, color= group, fill = group_fill)) +
          geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
          scale_color_manual(values = c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#333333"),  guide = FALSE) +
          scale_fill_manual(values = c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#FFFFFF")) +
          scale_x_discrete(breaks = 1:10) +
          theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, but time points 5-7 should be exactly like it have them with outlines, only the zeros should be invisible with no outline

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to display empty times just without any bar-line, there would be a way using base `barplot`. First we need the data in wide format, whcih can be achieved using `reshape` (you also could look into `?data.table::dcast`) and create two clones.

```
dat1 <- reshape(dat[-4], idvar="group", direction="wide")
dat1[] <- lapply(dat1, function(x) if (all(x == 0)) NA else x)  # set zeros to NA
dat1.1 <- dat1.2 <- dat1  # create clones
```

In one clone we set the "no times" to `NA`, in the other the opposites.

```
no.times <- paste0("value.", 1:7)

dat1.1[names(dat1) %in% no.times] <- NA
dat1.2[-which(names(dat1) %in% no.times)] <- NA
```

Now we can plot one plot over the other (using option `add=TRUE`) with different settings for `border` and `col`.

```
barplot(as.matrix(dat1.1[-1]), names.arg=1:10, 
        ylim=c(-.1, max(colSums(dat1[-1]), na.rm=TRUE) + .1),
        border=0, col=c("#56B4E9", "#E69F00"), 
        main="My plot", xlab="Time", ylab="Value")
barplot(as.matrix(dat1.2[-1]), names.arg=1:10,
        border=c("#56B4E9", "#E69F00"), col=NA, add=TRUE)
box()  # add box around plot
legend("topleft", legend=c("A", "B", "no"), pch=c(15, 15, 0),  # add legend
       col=c("#56B4E9", "#E69F00", "black"), title="Group")
```

### *Result*

[image]

***Data***

```
dat <- structure(list(time = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), value = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 1.37095844714667, 0.564698171396089, 0.363128411337339, 0.63286260496104, 
0.404268323140999, 0.106124516091484, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.51152199743894, 
0.0946590384130976, 2.01842371387704, 0.062714099052421, 1.30486965422349
), group = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), 
    group_fill = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("A", 
    "B", "no"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```